# Transmission power of Apple Wi-Fi antennas (EMF and health)

Tags: antenna, wifi, safety

(I hope this is the right place for this kind of question)

#### Background

I was looking a little bit into how *Wi-Fi affects our health* topic. While many people seem to be concerned about their Wi-Fi routers, I was curious about the Wi-Fi clients. Especially about how much Wi-Fi RF power is output by Apple devices (iPad, iPhone, MacBook). I couldn't find usable information on the net or Apple's antenna specification site.

#### Question

How much power in mW do typical Apple Wi-Fi product (iPads, iPhones, MacBooks) emit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maximum permissible power output for Part 15 operation is 1W; Apple devices are known to use up to that limit.

e.g. https://fccid.io/BCGA2589/Test-Report/WLAN-OFDMA-Test-Report-1-5691887.pdf

The above is a test report for the iPad Air 5th generation tablet. On page 3 you will see that the measured peak power output in 802.11ax mode using cyclic delay diversity (CDD) is about 967mW / 29.68dBm.

If you wish to research other products, you can find similar reports from the FCC's website.

However, it is very unlikely you will be able to draw any specific conclusions about health effects from these figures. Of more relevance will be the SAR (specific absorption rate) measurements.

To my knowledge, all Apple products have SAR measurements below the safe thresholds set by the FCC.

Comment: Conclusions regarding health effects are difficult. Important for me was the relation: Do I need to worry if my router uses 10mW or 100mW if my iPad runs on 1000mW anyways.

Comment: For perspective, up to 5w is considered safe for a handheld device.